# Maps and Wedge Products

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras

I'm currently trying to prove Cramers rule with the wedge product definition of a determinant. The proof hinges on the fact that if M is some map, then we can write:

$$ M\left(\vec a \wedge \vec b\right) = M\left( \vec a \right) \wedge M\left( \vec b \right) $$

However, I'm at a loss here, because I really don't understand why this should be true. IF M is a linear map, I thought linearity implies that $M(a+b) = M(a)+M(b)$, can anybody explain why the above identity is true?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Can you explain your notations? What is $\vec a$ (where does it live in?) and what is $\wedge$? What is $M(\vec a \wedge \vec b)$?

Comment: As I understand it, $\vec a$ is a vector in n dimensional space, and M is a map - which is like a matrix, that takes $\vec a $ and returns a new vector - like $A \vec x  = \vec b$ does in linear algebra. $\wedge$ is the standard wedge product operator.

Comment: Have you tried going into components and using some identity for an anti symmetric tensor?

Comment: So to clarify, applying the map M to the bivector returned by $\vec a \wedge \vec b$, produces the same bivector we would get if we apply the map to the vector a, then to the vector b; before finding the corresponding bivector with the wedge product

Comment: So let's say $M$ is a linear map from some vector space to itself. But $\vec a\wedge \vec b$ will live in a different vector space. So how do you interpret $M(\vec a \wedge \vec b)$?

Comment: I haven't tried that, no. I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you please elaborate :).

Comment: Thats exactly where my confusion comes from John. I don't see how this can be true, because I don't see how M can apply to both a bivector (LHS) and to a standard vector (RHS).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moPJKRRMxjk - IF you go to approximately 6:30, he's using the identity I've written above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perhaps a slight abuse of notation in that, as John pointed out, $M$ acting on a bivector $a \wedge b$ seems incompatible with the notion that $M$ acts on ordinary vectors.

A possible resolution to the notation issue would be to write, for vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k$,

$$M_{(k)} (v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_k) \equiv M(v_1) \wedge M(v_2) \wedge \ldots \wedge M(v_k)$$

And hence, given a linear operator $M$, we *also* define several other linear maps $M_{(2)}, M_{(3)}$, and so on.  Nevertheless, it's pretty common to just say $M(a \wedge b) \equiv M(a) \wedge M(b)$ since there's little chance of getting confused about what map you're applying.

Since each of the $M_{(k)}$ is technically distinct from the others, I think you should be able to accept that this is merely a convenient definition?  That we choose this definition might be motivated from the tensor product, but I must stress it is merely a convenient choice *until* one asks why and how this definition gives us $M_{(n)}(\epsilon) = (\det M) \epsilon$ for any $n$-vector $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for that, this clears things up a lot. But just to clarify, if M is a matrix, and we apply it to a: would the same matrix be applied to $ a \wedge b$? I know this is probably just repeating what you said - but I just want to be completely clear.

Comment: If you choose a basis, and write the linear map $M$ in terms of components in that basis, then the matrix representation of $M_{(2)}$ is going to be different from that of $M$.  Among other reasons, $M$ acts on common vectors, which have $n$ components, but $M_{(2)}$ acts on bivectors, which have $n(n-1)/2$ components.